# Using SubModules for Generic Assignments in Fortran

Tags: generics, module, fortran, assignment-operator, fortran2008

If we have three different Files with different Derived types,

**MyTypeMod.f90:**

```
MODULE MyTypeMod

TYPE, ABSTRACT :: MyType
INTEGER :: Num
END TYPE MyType

CONTAINS

END MODULE MyTypeMod
```

**MyType1Mod.f90**

```
MODULE MyType1Mod
USE MyTypeMod,  ONLY : MyType
USE MyType2Mod, ONLY : MyType2
IMPLICIT NONE

TYPE, EXTENDS(MyType) :: MyType1
CONTAINS
PROCEDURE :: Type1EqualsType2
GENERIC :: ASSIGNMENT(=) => Type1EqualsType2
END TYPE MyType1

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE Type1EqualsType2(Type1, Type2)
TYPE(MyType1), INTENT(OUT) :: Type1
TYPE(MyType2), INTENT(IN) :: Type2
Type1%Num = Type2%Num
END SUBROUTINE Type1EqualsType2

END MODULE MyType1Mod
```

**MyType2Mod.f90**

```
MODULE MyType1Mod
USE MyTypeMod,  ONLY : MyType
USE MyType1Mod, ONLY : MyType1
IMPLICIT NONE

TYPE, EXTENDS(MyType) :: MyType2
CONTAINS
PROCEDURE :: Type2EqualsType1
GENERIC :: ASSIGNMENT(=) => Type2EqualsType1
END TYPE MyType2

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE Type2EqualsType1(Type2, Type1)
TYPE(MyType2), INTENT(OUT) :: Type2
TYPE(MyType1), INTENT(IN) :: Type1
Type2%Num = Type1%Num
END SUBROUTINE Type2EqualsType1

END MODULE MyType2Mod
```

Here, In this case I couldn't able to compile the Program due to Module files Interdependent on each other. Can I use SubModules to solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "how we create submodules"? What do you want to achieve? Which part do you want to end up in a submodule? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you can't do quite what you want using submodules. This is because both functions `Type1EqualsType2` and `Type2EqualsType1` require both `MyType1` and `MyType2` in their function interfaces. Even if you use submodules, both functions will have to have interfaces in their respective modules, and so the circular dependency will remain.

However, there are a couple of possible workarounds:

### Select type

You can have the `intent(in)` arguments of both functions be `class(MyType)`, and only do type resolution using a `select type` statement. This will allow you to move the function definitions to submodules and resolve the circular dependency, but will also mean that you have to handle cases where a different type which extends `MyType` is passed to the function. Also, `select type` can be a little slow, depending on your use case.

Code for this would look something like:

```
MODULE MyTypeMod
  IMPLICIT NONE
  TYPE, ABSTRACT :: MyType
    INTEGER :: Num
  END TYPE MyType
END MODULE MyTypeMod

MODULE MyType1Mod
  USE MyTypeMod, ONLY : MyType
  IMPLICIT NONE
  
  TYPE, EXTENDS(MyType) :: MyType1
  CONTAINS
    PROCEDURE :: Type1EqualsType2
    GENERIC :: ASSIGNMENT(=) => Type1EqualsType2
  END TYPE
  
  interface
    module SUBROUTINE Type1EqualsType2(this, input)
      TYPE(MyType1), INTENT(OUT) :: this
      class(MyType), INTENT(IN) :: input
    END SUBROUTINE
  end interface
END MODULE

MODULE MyType2Mod
  USE MyTypeMod, ONLY : MyType
  IMPLICIT NONE
  
  TYPE, EXTENDS(MyType) :: MyType2
  CONTAINS
    PROCEDURE :: Type2EqualsType1
    GENERIC :: ASSIGNMENT(=) => Type2EqualsType1
  END TYPE
  
  interface
    module SUBROUTINE Type2EqualsType1(this, input)
      TYPE(MyType2), INTENT(OUT) :: this
      class(MyType), INTENT(IN) :: input
    END SUBROUTINE
  end interface
END MODULE

submodule (MyType1Mod) MyType1Submod
  use MyType2Mod, only : MyType2
  implicit none
contains
  module procedure MyType1EqualsMyType2
    select type(input); type is(MyType1)
      this%Num = input%Num
    type is(MyType2)
      this%Num = input%Num
    class default
      ! Some kind of error handling goes here.
    end select
  end procedure
end submodule

submodule (MyType2Mod) MyType2Submod
  use MyType1Mod, only : MyType1
  implicit none
contains
  module procedure MyType2EqualsMyType1
    select type(input); type is(MyType1)
      this%Num = input%Num
    type is(MyType2)
      this%Num = input%Num
    class default
      ! Some kind of error handling goes here.
    end select
  end procedure
end submodule
```

### Generic procedure

You can instead replace the type-bound `assignment(=)` definitions with generic `assignment(=)` definitions. This avoids the runtime polymorphism, but means you have to define the assignments in a new module.

This would look something like:

```
MODULE MyTypeMod
  IMPLICIT NONE
  TYPE, ABSTRACT :: MyType
    INTEGER :: Num
  END TYPE MyType
END MODULE MyTypeMod

MODULE MyType1Mod
  USE MyTypeMod, ONLY : MyType
  IMPLICIT NONE
  
  TYPE, EXTENDS(MyType) :: MyType1
  END TYPE
END MODULE

MODULE MyType2Mod
  USE MyTypeMod, ONLY : MyType
  IMPLICIT NONE
  
  TYPE, EXTENDS(MyType) :: MyType2
  END TYPE
END MODULE

module MyEqualsMod
  use MyType1Mod : only MyType1
  use MyType2Mod : only MyType2
  implicit none
  
  interface assignment(=)
    module procedure MyType1EqualsMyType2
    module procedure MyType2EqualsMyType1
  end interface
contains
  subroutine MyType1EqualsMyType2(this,input)
    type(MyType1), intent(out) :: this
    type(MyType2), intent(in) :: input
    this%Num = input%Num
  end subroutine

  subroutine MyType2EqualsMyType1(this,input)
    type(MyType2), intent(out) :: this
    type(MyType1), intent(in) :: input
    this%Num = input%Num
  end subroutine
end module
```